# why index store.size reduced so many?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is an index has many docs, recently add some new fields and full update the index, yesterday cat the index

```
health status index               uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   company             KTngnM6ASD-_KdU0FFAWRA   1   0   95889387     63357813     67.4gb         67.4gb
```

but today cat it again

```
health status index               uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   company             KTngnM6ASD-_KdU0FFAWRA   1   0   95891965      3368035     29.8gb         29.8gb
```

why store.size is reduced so many (merge and compression)?
and why docs.deleted is also become smaller(63357813 ==> 3368035)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deleted documents ratio was already pretty high before your update operation and a merge operation was about to be triggered.

By updating your index in place, you increased even more the deleted documents ratio, probably beyond a certain threshold that actually triggered a merge operation which expunged the deleted documents from your index and reduced the number of segments in the process.

What would have been interested to see is the results of `_cat/segments` **before and after** your update.